# delphi android app "Update to billing library 3 before this date"

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Just uploaded my app bundle and get this message:

> We've detected that this app is using an old version of Google Play Billing. By 1 November 2021, all app updates must use billing library version 3 or newer. Update to billing library 3 before this date

Is there a way to update this library? I'm using Delphi 10.4.2.

Comment: Are you actually using the Billing library in your project? If so, are you using it through an FMX provided wrapper, or are you accessing it more directly? Do you get this error even with a basic project? If you are using an FMX wrapper, then this is likely something that Embarcadero will have to address on their end.

Comment: "Is there a way to update this library?" Billing API v3 is a very different implementation and will require Embarcadero to update the In-App Purchasing code. Please see: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-32139. If you require a login to view the report, please go to: https://my.embarcadero.com/#register

Comment: it seems that we have to wait for a new delphi update, thanks cap!

Comment: ..or someone else might be able to implement it

Comment: It would be better if Delphi/Embarcadero would disconnect these kind Technology implementions from the core Delphi (IDE), so updates would not be limited by the speed of Delphi updates/upgrades...